# Kibana Vega Infinite extent for field error

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite

I am creating scatter plot and its working fine until I choose time range from calendar which does not contain data. I have data until May 2021 so when I go for 1 Year its fine, but when I choose last 4 months, it gives me error - for X axis **Infinite extent for field "time": [Infinity, -Infinity]** and also error for Y axis **Infinite extent for field "Kilometers": [Infinity, -Infinity]**.

Its probably problem in date conversation but why its working for periods containing data and why is it giving me error for kilometers as well. Any help here please?

Elastic query returns timefield in unix time.

Thank you

(I have same problem also with line chart in vega)

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byYYl.png)

```
   {
  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.6.0.json
  data: {
    url: {
      %context%: true
      %timefield%: timefield
      index: indextrains
      body: {
        size: 10000
        _source: [
          timefield
          km
        ]
      }
    }
    format: {
      property: hits.hits
    }
  }
  transform: [
    {
      calculate: datetime(datum._source['timefield'])
      as: time
    }
    {
      calculate: datum._source['km']
      as: Kilometers
    }
  ]
  mark: {
    type: circle
  }
  encoding: {
    x: {
      field: time
      type: temporal
    }
    y: {
      field: Kilometers
      type: quantitative
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Freedy, I'm facing the same issue, wonder did you manage to address the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue using `query` within `body` section of the data source. Refer to my post/answer of [infinite extent for field error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77101128/how-to-resolve-infinite-extent-for-field-if-the-field-is-not-in-all-ingested-d).